# Creating a transparent picturebox class

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

My problem is that I want to put a picturebox with a png on a button, but WinForms doesn't seem to support transparency there.
1. Yes, I've tried Parent
2. Yes, I've tried Color.Transparent

The last try [I had](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/f43ed61e-6e15-41f8-801d-1e908810eed2/) didn't work either and I'm kinda clueless about it. Maybe you can help me. However this is the closest try I had so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Parameter2
{
    public class TransPicturebox : Control
    {
        public TransPicturebox()
        {
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }

        private Image _Image;

        public Image Image
        {
            get
            {
                return _Image;
            }
            set
            {
                _Image = value;
            }
        }

        private bool _autoscale = true;

        public bool AutoScale
        {
            get
            {
                return _autoscale;
            }
            set
            {
                _autoscale = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            if (_Image != null) //keep from crashing if there is no image
            {
                if (_autoscale)
                {
                    //Auto Scale the image to fit in the text box
                    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
                    Size size = this.Image.Size;
                    float num = Math.Min((float)(((float)base.ClientRectangle.Width) / ((float)size.Width)), (float)(((float)base.ClientRectangle.Height) / ((float)size.Height)));
                    rectangle.Width = (int)(size.Width * num);
                    rectangle.Height = (int)(size.Height * num);
                    rectangle.X = (base.ClientRectangle.Width - rectangle.Width) / 2;
                    rectangle.Y = (base.ClientRectangle.Height - rectangle.Height) / 2;

                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(_Image, rectangle);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(_Image, new Point(0, 0));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the image itself support transparency? It should, so it doesn't draw the "background" of the image in `Graphics.DrawImage`.

Comment: When setting a transparant PNG image as source for a PictureBox (the Image property), I don't have any problems seeing it transparent. I admit, I did it through the visual editor, but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Styxxy: I am almost certain that the OP wants the PictureBox itself to be transparent.  It has nothing to do with the image that it is displaying.  Jack W: Use WPF or read: [Making a Transparent Control in WinForms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26878/Making-Transparent-Controls-with-C-and-NET-3-5).  I've done it, you have to get creative, sometimes this means drawing child controls onto the topmost control yourself.

Comment: Even so, it is transparent for me. Changing my form background to red it also will turn the transparent part of my PictureBox into red. Note: I haven't tried the exact same thing as in the OP, which might cause different behaviour (though it sounds strange).

Comment: @Styxxy The problem would be that the image will be transparent *to the parent* to which it belongs (the form, usually). If  you have to picture boxes containing transparent images, and you put one over the other, you will see a square-shaped boundary in the color of the parent's background. That isn't **true** transparency.

Comment: Thanks @YoryeNathan, I'm a little bit wiser now :).

Comment: Does anything mentioned in this question help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918353/c-sharp-alpha-blend-transparent-picturebox