# Make Image Slowly Visible on Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, picturebox, progress

The idea is building a windows form application in Visual Studio 2010 using C#.

The program will run a series of operation when the user hit a button.

Is it possible to use a image to show the progress instead of using a progress bar?

So the idea is that the image will start of being invisible, and as the program progress, the image become more and more visible.

```
0% - invisible
50% - half transparent
100% - visible
```

I know you can toggle the PictureBox to be visible or not (PictureBox.Visible = true or false;), but is there a way to make it in between?

Any idea is appreciate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.DrawImage with opacity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519956/drawimage-with-opacity)

Comment: What you want can be achieved by a `splash from` indicating progress. Isn't it simpler?

Comment: [Here's a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918353/c-sharp-alpha-blend-transparent-picturebox), it sounds like it's going to be ugly

Comment: `The idea is building a windows form application` - winforms is not recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications. Precisely because of the complete lack of interactivity features such as animations. You can do this in WPF with 1 line of XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manipulating images in winforms is slow, so do this as little as possible:

```
public Bitmap ImageFade( Bitmap sourceBitmap, byte Transparency)
    {
        BitmapData sourceData = sourceBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,
                                    sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height),
                                    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        byte[] pixelBuffer = new byte[sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height];
        byte[] resultBuffer = new byte[sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height];

        Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, pixelBuffer, 0, pixelBuffer.Length);

        sourceBitmap.UnlockBits(sourceData);

        byte blue = 0;
        byte green = 0;
        byte red = 0;
        byte a = 0;

        int byteOffset = 0;

        for (int offsetY = 0; offsetY <
             sourceBitmap.Height; offsetY++)
        {
            for (int offsetX = 0; offsetX <
                 sourceBitmap.Width; offsetX++)
            {
                blue = 0;
                green = 0;
                red = 0;
                a = 0;

                byteOffset = offsetY *
                                sourceData.Stride +
                                offsetX * 4;

                blue += pixelBuffer[byteOffset];
                green += pixelBuffer[byteOffset + 1];
                red += pixelBuffer[byteOffset + 2];
                a += Transparency;//pixelBuffer[byteOffset + 3];

                resultBuffer[byteOffset] = blue;
                resultBuffer[byteOffset + 1] = green;
                resultBuffer[byteOffset + 2] = red;
                resultBuffer[byteOffset + 3] = a;
            }
        }

        Bitmap resultBitmap = new Bitmap(sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height);

        BitmapData resultData = resultBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0,
                                resultBitmap.Width, resultBitmap.Height),
                                ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        Marshal.Copy(resultBuffer, 0, resultData.Scan0, resultBuffer.Length);
        resultBitmap.UnlockBits(resultData);

        return resultBitmap;
    }
```

I note another answer uses SetPixel.  Avoid using that function if possible.  It's much faster to edit the underlying bytestream, which is still slow since it's not hardware accelerated, but it's the best of several not-great options

This function can potentially be further optimized, but I leave that as an exercise for the reader

Answer (score 0):

You could always adjust the alpha component of your image:

```
void SetImageProgress(float percent, Bitmap img)
{
   int alpha = (int)(percent / 100.0f * 255.0f);
   alpha &= 0xff;
   for(int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
   {
      for(int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
      {
         Color c = img.GetPixel(x, y);
         c = Color.FromArgb(alpha, c.R, c.G, c.B);
         img.SetPixel(x, y, c);
      }
   }
}
```